# Find $w$ such that $w^8=15-15i$

Tags: complex-numbers

Find the complex number, lying in the second quadrant, and having the smallest possible real part, which satisfies the equation

$$w^8=15-15i$$

Comment: dang, im sry, got the syntax wrong, its suppose to be w^8=15-15*I(imaginary number);

Comment: Rewrite $w^8$ in the [polar form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Polar_form): $r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$. Then, see the [de Moivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$z=15-15i\Longrightarrow |z|=15\,\sqrt 2\,\exp({7\pi i}/{4}+2k\pi i),\,k\in\Bbb Z$$

$$\Longrightarrow w^8=z\Longrightarrow w=z^{1/8}=15^{1/8}\,2^{1/16}\,\exp({7\pi i}/32+{k\pi i}/{4})$$

Now just observe that as $\,k\,$ runs from $\,0\,$ to $\,7\,$, we get all the possible (eight) values on the right-hand side above...

Comment: Wow, second typo discovered now. Of course, it shall be corrected now. Thanks @AndréNicolas

Answer (score 2):

Hint: use the polar form of complex numbers.